# how can I run an SQL script from local drive on server?

Tags: oracle, command-line, sqlplus

I'm connected to a server with sql,

I did,

```
SQL>@/path/to/file.sql
```

but got an `SP2-0310: unable to open file` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try go the folder where's the script first, then connect to the server and run SQL>file.sql. With MySQL this works.

Answer (score 1):

try double quotes around the whole thing after the @ sign @"..."

Comment: can also check permissions on the file.sql

Comment: so while in SQL*Plus type "set echo on"   then @"<path/file.sql>"

Answer (score 1):

Is the .sql file on the server, or on your client system? It must reside on the client system for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this in Unix, but if you are starting in Windows, go into the Properties of the Icon you use to start SQL*Plus and set the "Start in:" field to include the path to your script.  Assuming the file is on dive A: for this example you would put 
A:\Path\to\File
Then just use @file.sql at the prompt (or just @file since the default extension is ".sql").

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, though. He's doing this with command-line, and your answer doesn't address that issue.